# NHibernate QueryOver Restrinctions on a variable

Tags: nhibernate, restrictions, queryover

I've a little problem: I would insert a condition into my QueryOver that checks also the variable value. Something like this:

```
 var qOver = QueryOver.Of<MyModel>(() => myMod)
                .JoinAlias(() => myMod.SubMod, () => subMod, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .Where(Restrictions.Or(
                        Restrictions.On(() => myMod.ID).IsIn(MyIDList)
                        , Restrictions.On(MyIDList == null))
```

In SQL sintax something like

```
WHERE @Variable = '' OR MyTable.MyField = @Variable
```

So, if I my variable is filled I'll filter on my field. If my variable is empty (or null) I'll select every record without filter any content.

How can I reach this result using QueryOver and Restrinctions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the variable is null or not set, dont add it to your query.

```
var qOver = QueryOver.Of<MyModel>(() => myMod)
    .JoinAlias(() => myMod.SubMod, () => subMod, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

if( MyIDList != null )
    qOver = qOver.Where(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.On(() => myMod.ID).IsIn(MyIDList))
```

Comment: Impossible...such an easy solution that cannot almost believe it :) Yeah it works fine!!! Thank you!!